# Why `numpy.fft.irfft` is so imprecise?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I understand that most FFT/IFFT routines have an error floor.  I was expecting NumPy's FFT to have an error floor in the same orders as FFTW (say `1e-15`), but the following experiment shows errors in the order of `1e-5`.

Consider calculating the IDFT of a box.  It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Some_discrete_Fourier_transform_pairs) that the result is the sinc-like Dirichlet kernel.  But that is not what I get from `numpy.fft.irfft`.  In fact even the first sample that should simply equal the width of the box divided by the number of FFT points is off by an amount around `4e-5` as the following example shows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.special import diric

N = 40960
K = 513

X = np.ones(K, dtype=np.complex)
x = np.fft.irfft(X, N)

print("x[0] = %g: expected %g - error = %g" % (x[0], (2*K+1)/N, x[0]-(2*K+1)/N))

# expected IDFT of a box is Dirichlet function (see
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Some_discrete_Fourier_transform_pairs)

y = diric(2*np.pi*np.arange(N)/N, 2*K+1) * (2*K+1) / N

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x[:1024] - y[:1024])
plt.title('error')

plt.show(block=True)
```

It looks like the error is of sinusoidal form:
[image]

Has anybody experience same issue? Am I misunderstanding something about the NumPy's FFT pack or it is just not accurate?

---

### Update

Here is the equivalent of part of the script in Octave:

```
N = 40960;
K = 513;

X = zeros(1, N);


X(1:K) = 1;
X(N-K:N) = 1;

x = ifft(X);

fprintf("x[0] = %g, expected = %g - error = %g\n", x(1), (2*K+1)/N, x(1)-(2*K+1)/N);
```

The error on `x[0]` is practically zero in Octave.  (I did not check other samples because I am not aware of equivalent of `diric` function in Octave.)

Comment: Are you sure a FFTW equivalent would produce a "better" result? If so, show the script. The doc of `numpy.fft` says it uses [Cooley-Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) which is not an approximate algorithm, and I doubt it generates much more numerical noise than alternatives.

Comment: @Leporello I was also expecting the algorithm to be precise up to numerical errors.  But the fact that even `x[0]` is not correct (it must equal the average of input) shows there is something wrong.  I add an Octave script to the question that shows at least Octave's implementation calculates the correct `x[0]` (though I did not check the other samples in Octave).

Comment: The `X` arrays in your NumPy and Octave code appear to be inequivalent; the NumPy array doesn't have anything like the `X(N-K:N) = 1;` in the Octave.

Comment: It almost looks like you're off by one in one of the args to dirichlet or something.

Comment: @user2357112 That's because Octave does not have specific 'real' FFT/IFFT routines.  So, I had to specify full input to IFFT, hence I set the elements corresponding to negative frequencies to one as well.

Comment: Please draw the same plot in octave

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `X = np.ones(K+1, dtype=np.complex)`? (Or equivalently, `2*K-1` in place of `2*K + 1` in the expected result.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks!  Indeed my example was wrong.  Applying the correction you mentioned I get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [MarkDickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson), I realized that my math was wrong.  The correct comparison would be carried out by:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.special import diric

N = 40960
K = 513

X = np.ones(K+1, dtype=np.complex)
x = np.fft.irfft(X, N)

print("x[0] = %g: expected %g - error = %g" % (x[0], (2*K+1)/N, x[0]-(2*K+1)/N))

# expected IDFT of a box is Dirichlet function (see
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Some_discrete_Fourier_transform_pairs)

y = diric(2*np.pi*np.arange(N)/N, 2*K+1) * (2*K+1) / N

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x[:1024] - y[:1024])
plt.title('error')

plt.show(block=True)
```

that shows `irfft` is accurate. Here is the error plot:
[image]

Numpy is correct, my math was incorrect.  I am sorry for posting this misleading question.  I don't know what is the standard procedure in these cases.  Should I delete my question or leave it here with this answer?  I just don't want it to be undermining NumPy or challanging its accuracy (as this was clearly a false alarm).